# Macros that can scan the contents of their arguments

Tags: macros, programming

I was thinking that it since the architecture of LaTeX is a collection of pre-processors on top of TeX, that it may be possible that some macros could in theory do some sort of find-and-replace within the arguments of stuff that they receive.

**Motivation**:
We have a lot of math environments. A lot of them can really be unified into one, if one could scan for the presence of certain elements within the input. For example: a `sequation` environment, that is unnumbered if it doesn't detect a `\label` macro, a multiline `breqn` environment if it sees an unbalanced long equation with optional line breaks, and an `align` without `split` if it sees multiple patterns of `= &` or some such.

**Question**:
Is it possible to write such macros/environments, and if it is, how do I do that?

**Attempt at a solution**:
I have a gnawing suspicion that the `cleveref` package has something interesting. The trouble is that it has lots of reference semantics too, and it might only be possible to look for some things specific to cleveref, that are not as useful for what I want to do.

Comment: You wrote, "We have a lot of math environments. A lot of them can really be unified into one..." What problem are you looking to solve?

Comment: Basically, I want a single equation environment that does the right thing. I want to remove the mental overhead of using `breqn`, `align`, `aligned`, `equation`, `eqnarray`, and have the program determine what is best. It's like cleveref for equations.

Comment: cleveref is the wrong track. There are tools to scan the input and look for patterns, e.g. in expl3 there is a regex module and imho tex4ht is using it to create mathml from the math. But the main problem is not to scan, but to define good rules--and to avoid that it slows down compilation a lot if you have many rules.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, this sounds promising, and exactly the kind of programming challenge that I should tackle.

Comment: one issue is that your first sentence is essentially wrong. unlike say the C macro pre-processor, latex does not work as a pre-processor, so in the normal processing, tex doesn't have access to the full content of an environment before it starts processing.  For your specific question, "just use `breqn`" is intended to be the answer breqn _by design_ is trying to make these choices automatically. The fact that it doesn't work all the time and you need to manually choose to use align  in some cases even if using breqn elsewhere is an indication that automating this choice is likely to be hard

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'd rather contribute code to `breqn`, than spend the next few years of my life ruminating over whether I should use `align` or `eqnarray`.

Comment: breqn was an interesting experiment but it's not clear it's the best starting point and its development has been stalled for 20 years

Comment: but the choice between align and eqnarray is trivial: never use eqnarray.

Comment: The set of tokens contained in whatsoever equation-environment might form an (almost) arbitrary expansion-based algorithm. How far to go with expanding before searching for whatsoever patterns? E.g., how to detect the presence of `\label` if `\label` is not written directly but instead a macro is written where the expansion-chain at some stage (probably beneath other things) yields a token that was made equal to `\label` via `\let`? How to crank malicious user's input like `\gobbletwo\label{No, thank you!}`?

Comment: "I want to remove the mental overhead of using breqn, align, aligned, equation, eqnarray, and have the program determine what is best"  I think that this is a misguided aim. Firstly the choice between breqn and align is the choice between automatic and manual line breaking. Clearly it is not possible to make that choice automatically. The choice between align and equation is simple: use equation if it is 1  line, arguably align could act as equation if 1 line but that would be a modification to align not via any pre-processor parse. The choice for eqnarray is simple: do not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides `\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}` that allows you to search for `<search>` within `<cmd>` and replace it with `<replace>`. It also allows for branching whether the replacement resulted in `<success>` or `<failure>`. I've used this approach below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Generic math display
\NewEnviron{mathenvironment}{%
  % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  \patchcmd{\BODY}
    {\label}% Search for \label
    {\label}% If found, replace with \label
    {% \label is present
      \patchcmd{\BODY}
        {&}% Search for &
        {&}% If found, replace with &
        {% \label and & is present
          \begin{align}
            \BODY
          \end{align}
        }{% \label is present, but & is not
          \begin{equation}
            \BODY
          \end{equation}
        }%
    }
    {% \label is not present
      \[
        \BODY
      \]
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mathenvironment}
  f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c
\end{mathenvironment}

\begin{mathenvironment}
  f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c \label{eqn:quadratic-1}
\end{mathenvironment}

\begin{mathenvironment}
  f(x) &= a_1 x^2 + b_1 x + c_1 \label{eqn:quadratic-2} \\
  g(y) &= a_2 y^2 + b_2 y + c_2 \label{eqn:quadratic-3}
\end{mathenvironment}

\end{document}
```

The entire body of `mathenvironment` is captured inside `\BODY`, then patched to identify elements that exist (or not) and condition accordingly. You can nest these if needed to look at a combination of elements and condition accordingly.

Note that `\patchcmd` is looking for an *explicit* match, so won't find anything implicit (like searching for `\test`, say, where `\test` is part of the expansion/replacement text for a macro within `mathenvironment`). So if you have macros that act as replacements for search items it will fail.

If you have numerous cases that you want to search for, with exclusions, it's probably best to use regular expressions to identify the patterns that you want to condition on, rather than nesting content inside `\patchcmd`. These regular expressions might be handled better using LaTeX3.

Comment: This sounds along the right track of what I was looking for.The `etoolbox` package lacks regular expression facilities, do you mean to use external pre-processing with regular expressions?

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan: I'd suggest using regular expressions (supported through LaTeX3) for processing `\BODY` and condition based on that. I'm not familiar with regular expressions, so I can't help there.